# Find surface area when this function is rotated around the y-axis. $y = \frac{1}{3} x^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: integration

I am gonna rotate this function around the y-axis, and I have to find the surface area.

Quick question: the reason we can use either definition (either derivative with respect to x or y) of arc length is because both definitions of arc length give you the... arc length unsurprisingly. We just need the arc length. It feels odd to find the surface area here with respect to dy, but find the arc length using a derivative with respect to x... but it shouldnt right?

Anyway, onto the problem:

$$y = \frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$ when $0 \leq x \leq 12$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\frac{dy^2}{dx} = \frac{1}{4} x$$

$$SA = 2 \pi \int_0^{12} x \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4}x} dx$$

But now I'm stuck here...I can't usub? Can I just multiply out converting $x$ to $\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: Bring the $x$ inside the radical ($x\ge 0$ here), complete the square, and integrate.

Comment: Set $x=\dfrac{1}{4}\cot^2\theta$.

Comment: Mind showing me? I'm a bit lost as to what you mean? Especially the trig sub...

Comment: @rogerl mind showing a bit?

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Let }\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \mathrm dx\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/4\cdot\cot^2\theta\\ -1/2\cdot \cot\theta\csc^2\theta\mathrm d\theta\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{aligned}\int x\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{4x}}\mathrm dx&=-\dfrac{1}{8}\int\cot^2\theta \sec\theta \cot\theta\csc^2\theta\mathrm d\theta\\&=-\dfrac{1}{8}\int\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}\cdot\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\mathrm d\theta\\ &=-\dfrac{1}{8}\int\cot^2\theta\csc^2\theta\mathrm d\theta\end{aligned}$$

Now simply let $u=\cot\theta\implies \mathrm du=-\csc^2\theta\mathrm d\theta$. Can you proceed?

---

Post OP's edit

$$\begin{aligned}\int x\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{4}x}\mathrm dx&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int x\sqrt{x+4}\mathrm dx\end{aligned}$$

Let $u=x+4\iff x=u-4\implies \mathrm du=\mathrm dx$

$$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{1}{2}\int x\sqrt{x+4}\mathrm dx&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{u}(u-4)\mathrm du\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int \left(u^{3/2}-4\sqrt{u}\right)\mathrm du\end{aligned}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I think the 1/4x is wrong... I made a mistake, the x should not be in the denominator?

Comment: Either way... where did the sec ceom from?

Comment: That is because $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$.

Comment: Ohhh.. This is a pretty innovative approach. Do you see how to complete the square? I'd like to see that approach but got stuck as well. Any idea?

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this any other way?

Comment: I think you could use integration by parts.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Simply the Power rule gives the antiderivative.

Comment: You're right.   With substitution.

Comment: How do you use the power rule here?

Comment: The power rule holds for all real numbers be it fractions, decimals or integers. So that you have $$\int x^n\mathrm dx = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: So I'm following but now I seem to have a problem with the limits of integration. The limits to start have to be converted to y right because we're rotating around the y axis? So I get that the limits of integration are from 0 to $8 \sqrt{3}$ and then after the u sub, using $u = x+4$, the limits turn into 0 and $8 \sqrt{3} + 4$....this does not play nicely right?

Comment: You can simply undo the substitution once you've found the antiderivative, once you do that the same limits i.e. $0$ and $12$ apply as they did on the integral we were supposed to find.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something about what limits of integration to use... if the arc length formula that I use uses dy, then the limits of integration have to be for y. Conversely, if the arc length formula I use uses dx, then the limits have to be for x right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Use integration by parts.   We have $\int x\sqrt{1+\frac14 x}\operatorname {dx}=x(\frac83)(1+\frac14 x)^{\frac32} -(\frac83) \int (1+\frac14 x)^{\frac32}\operatorname {dx}$.

Comment: Where did the 8/3 come from?

Comment: To correct for the $\frac32$ and $\frac14 $ when you differentiate.